# Unknown argument \"hasNextPage\" on field \"pageInfo\" GraphQL

Tags: graphql, pagination

How to implement pagination for graphQL Query? I keep receiving:

> "message": "Unknown argument "hasNextPage" on field "pageInfo" of type "Core_EventPeopleConnection"."

```
query myquery($viewId: ID!,$hasNextPage: Boolean!, $endCursor: String!){
  Core_eventPeopleListView(viewId: $viewId){
    id
    people{
      pageInfo(hasNextPage: true,endCursor: $endCursor){
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
     nodes{
      firstName
      lastName
      jobTitle
      organization
      websiteUrl
    } 
    }
    }    
    }
Variables:
        {
      "viewId":"RXZlbnRWaWV3XzMyMTY1Mw==",
      "endCursor": "WyJhZ2Fyd2FsIiwic2hydXRpIiwiUlhabGJuUlFaVzl3YkdWZk1UVXhPREkzTlRVPSJd",
      "hasNextPage": true
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Relay specification, `hasNextPage` is not an argument, but a field that is returned from the API to tell you if you can paginate further. Just remove the argument:

```
query myquery($viewId: ID!,$hasNextPage: Boolean!, $endCursor: String!){
  Core_eventPeopleListView(viewId: $viewId){
    id
    people{
      pageInfo(endCursor: $endCursor){
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      nodes{
        firstName
        lastName
        jobTitle
        organization
        websiteUrl
      } 
    }
  }    
}
```